# python find string concatenations and replace them with actual strings

Tags: python, regex, string

Tried finding an answer for this but haven't been able to exactly find what I'm looking for. I'm trying to create a python script that will find strings concatenations in a text file, and transform them into a single string.

For example, the file would contain:

```
"h" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o" + world;
```

An I'd like to have a script turn this into:

```
"hello" + world;
```

If something like this is feasible, could I get some pointers on how to write such script?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're trying to optimize some kind of code, chances are the language is already doing it for you. (Python does.)

Comment: Why bother?  CPython peephole optimizer does it for you anyway.  Search for "constant folding"

Comment: if your question is __Is this possible at all?__ the answer is __of coarse__

Comment: I'm doing this for readability purposes, if there's a file full of concats like these it's pretty easy to get lost in it.

Comment: @kindall: Well, it will do this for you in the OP's specific case. But it won't handle `hello + 'w' + 'o' + 'r' + 'l' + 'd'` because it can't be sure of the type of `hello`, and it's required to evaluate from left-to-right, and adding a larger string may not be equivalent to adding each smaller string one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove `" + "` when it is found.  Ostensibly, it should only be found between two strings that are being concatenated.  The regular expression below will drop the following sequence: a double quote, 0 or 1 whitespace characters, the plus sign, 0 or 1 whitespace characters, and an other double quote.

```
import re

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fp:
    cleaned_text = [re.sub(r'"\W?\+\W?"', '',line) for line in fp]

# example
> re.sub(r'"\W?\+\W?"', '','"h" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o" + world;')
# "hello" world;
```

Comment: Search-and-replace without context is not safe. `a + " + " + b`

Comment: This applies perfectly to the example specified above, which is what I needed. Much appreciated.